# Vim undofile does not work when file is too long

Tags: filesystem, undo-redo

I use a vim persistent undo setup as follows, which have worked all that way here.

```
set undofile
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
```

However now I'm facing a problem when the undofile became too long, notice that an undofile has a name in the form of absolute path like `%home%user%directory%...%directory%file` that means if your file has a big name, is under a big path directory or both, the chances for reaching the linux file name max length will be higher. In my case, when try to save the open file it raises the error:

```
E828: Cannot open undo file for writing: /home/user/.vim/undodir/%home%user%workspace%%app%javascript%packs%domains%components%grid%column_cell_factory%inspection_cell_factory.jsx
```

How can I manage in order to keep my persistent undo working even for these situations?

**UPDATE**

A satisfactory workaround could be a way for vim dynamically detect the error and then change the store path for a local aside the current file.

**UPDATE**

This is not my real filename, I removed username and others personal information intentionally, at the end they are not relevant and don't contain any special char. The file length is 160, and the whole path with the folder it should be stored is 189 length.

Comment: I think default max filename length is 255 bytes on linux. The example you posted is only 116 characters (counting after the last slash in its path...paths can be 4096 bytes). (I'm assuming that's all ASCII/UTF-8 so one byte per character).

Comment: You can check system setting with `getconf NAME_MAX /mnt/DEVICE`. Can you confirm UTF-8 and ASCII characters only? Otherwise, are you sure there's not something else going on like a permissions problem?

Comment: @BLayer this is not the real path, I removed real username and others information. I will edit the question with the real length

Comment: But you're still well under 255? Maybe you should still check/confirm the things I mentioned.

Comment: You are right, my output was 255 for `getconf NAME_MAX /` however it is 143 for `getconf NAME_MAX ~/` and others folders below `$HOME`

Comment: Are you using an encrypted file system or FUSE overlay or something there?

Comment: my guess is you are using an encrypted filesystem, in which case the limit is about 145 characters.

Comment: Yes, my home is another mount partition encrypted by the encrypt filesystem of the OS (which I dont know exaclty which is, I use linux mint)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Beat you by 58 seconds. ;)

Comment: I'd start with checking documentation for that to see if there's any way to work around the limit. Some encryption solutions do stupid stuff like prepend a too-long identifier to names.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32834/303213

Comment: @BLayer Darn it!

Comment: did you find any solution for this? my undofile doesn't work for some reason, although i think it will turn out to be something else, perhaps i get lucky! 

Comment: @cregox I made this question also on SO 3 years ago, and last week someone brought an acceptable answer that solves this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289924/vim-undofile-does-not-work-when-file-is-too-long/75965636#75965636

Comment: There is a plugin that solves this issue on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289924/vim-undofile-does-not-work-when-file-is-too-long/75965636#75965636

Comment: thanks! you can also answer it yourself here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that rewrites the undo file as a path instead of one long filename:

https://github.com/pixelastic/vim-undodir-tree

So instead of `%home%user%directory%...%directory%file` you get `/home/user/directory/.../directory/file` for your undo file.

Comment: Maybe should we mention that this answer is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75965636) one.